# Can not use datetime type in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have tried to make a column using datetime type in MySQL workbench.
 but, when I select datetime type it occurs an error like

> Could not set new data type The given data type DATETIME contains
>   errors and cannot be accepted. The previous value is kept instead"

How can I use this type?

Comment: Remove the '(6)' part.

Comment: try this :- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70125

Comment: What version of Workbench? There was a bug https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68870. I use last version on Mac and that bug is gone.

Comment: I have resolve this problem. If someone has problem like me, just type datetime not datetime().

Comment: @JaeyoungLee - Glad you found a solution. You should have posted that as an "answer". Then it will be more visible to others, and can also be upvoted. Answering your own question is allowed on Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I had this problem, you need to make sure that when you select the data type you change datetime() to datetime with no ().

From MySQL 5.6.4 onwards DATETIME can have subseconds, the level of precision being defined in the (), if you are not using subseconds then simply remove this all together. This also applies to the TIME and TIMESTAMP Datatypes.

[For more info see here](https://dzone.com/articles/recovering-temporal-types)

Answer (score 8):

> As of 5.6.4 TIME, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME can have a fractional part. To create a field with subseconds you can specify precision in brackets: TIME(3), DATETIME(6) etc.

```
time(3)      = 05:05:10.000 (3 precision )
timestamp(6) = 2013-07-04 05:05:10.000000 (6 precision )
datetime(1)  = 2013-07-04 05:05:10.0 (1 precision )
datetime     = 2013-07-04 05:05:10 (0 precision )
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-create the initial workbench connection or reset the advanced connection properties to update the server version. If the server has been upgraded and the workbench connection is not updated the workbench still thinks it is working with the old version and therefore restricts and flags the datetime(x) as an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a value into the parenthesis.  For example, use DATETIME(4) instead of DATETIME().

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when you want to give column data type as varchar() with no parameter.

Please write the amount inside the data type like varchar(50).